# Is this a common pattern faced in Computer Science?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, discrete-mathematics, computation-theory

I have a container that has 2 ethernet links inside it. Lets call the container C1 and the ethernet links as EL1, EL2. So C1 has EL1 and EL2.

I represent the relationship as `C1 -> EL1, EL2`

Now the Ethernet links can pass through more than just one container. For example EL2 can pass through C1 and C2 containers.

```
EL2 -> C1, C2
```

C2 can have other Ethernet links inside that as well. For example,

```
C2 -> EL2, EL3
```

The same goes for EL3 as well..........

Now when some Ethernet links fails, I need find the related containers and Ethernet links. For example if EL2 fails I have to group C1 and C2, since they are immediate parents to EL2. Then in the same group I will add EL1 and EL3 as well since they are children of C1 and C2. If EL3 has more containers related to it, I need to group that as well.

It looks like an endless chain to me. Since I am new to computer science, I wonder if this is an already existing problem faced in the field of computing or programming. So that is what I am asking in this question as well. If it is indeed, is there a name for that, so that I can study about that.

I hope I am clear enough what I meant in the description.

Comment: So you want to find all elements that are "related" by following Container and Links? That would be something like a recursive aggregation, where you only recurse down when the link is not yet in the list?

Comment: Exactly. I can stop finding the related Containers and Links, if , in the nth recursion, I find no new container or links.

Comment: But there is no gaurantee like that since the data I work with is from the real time network. So I have to stop at some point to avoid the endless loop in my Java program.

Comment: There can not be an endless loop, you only go down one level if the ethernet link is not yet in the list. When doing aggregation you are basically passing the current list of items found around.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But each step to get the Container for link or Link for container is  a database call, which is very expensive. Each time the resources I have to look up in the database grows exponentially. At some point on iteration was taking more that 10 mins to return from database call. That is when I decided to look up if this is standard problem faced by many programmers.

Comment: If you represent you containers and links relations as a graph then the problem turns into well known problem of computing connected components: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can represent your Ethernet links and Containers as an undirected graph network. Then given a failed Ethernet link you can traverse this graph (for e.g a DFS traversal) to find all nodes reachable from the failed link node. This should give you all the containers and ethernet links connected to the failed link. Your above example shown as an undirected graph below-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudo code:

```
input: Set<EthernetLink> failingLinks

Set<Container> failingContainers = new Set<>
Set<Container> allContainers = new Set<>
Set<EthernetLink> allLinks = new Set<>

while(true) {
  failingLinks.removeAll(allLinks)
  if (failingLinks is empty)
    break;
  allLinks.addAll(failingLinks)

  failingContainers = select from... where link in (failingLinks)
  failingContainers.removeAll(allContainers)
  if (failingContainers is empty)
    break;
  allContainers.addAll(failingContainers)

  failingLinks = select from... where container in (failingContainer)
}

return {allLinks, allContainers}
```

It calculates set unions and differences in memory and search for new connections only for the new objects.